# sum over floating points of the form 3.016e-06 using awk

Tags: awk, floating-point

I want to sum over floats of the form: 3.016e-06
The floats are saved in a files called S_3x3.txt S_4x4.txt ... S_8x8.txt
My code sums only the first integer. Instead of 3.016e-06 + 4.022e-06 it calculates 3 + 4. How can I fix this?

```
    x=3
    while [ $x -le 8 ]
    do
        find . -name "S_$((x))x$((x))*" -print | sort -t'_' -nk3 | 
        xargs -J {} awk -F' ' 'FNR == 1 && !/^($|#)/{ sum+=$1) }END{ 
        print sum }' {} >> cS_CPU.txt
    x=$(( x+1 ))
    done
```

Comment: can you provide two input files ? with data and skipped lines ? you awk code will only collect data on forst line of every file (along with no '$' and no '#') is that what you want ?

Comment: `"S_$((x))x$((x))*"` -- that's a funny place to use arithmetic evaluation. Why not `"S_${x}x${x}*"`

Comment: are you sure the "-" in the exponent is not a lookalike char? pass through `cat -vet` to see.

Comment: works for me with gawk, nawk, mawk. What version of awk are you working with?

Comment: my version is: awk version 20070501

Comment: My version was really to old. Downloaded the GNU command line tools including gawk. It works just fine now :)

Answer (score 0):

not an answer, but too long for a comment

```
    x=3
    while [ $x -le 8 ]
    do
        find . -name "S_${x}x${x}*" -print | sort -t'_' -nk3 | 
        xargs -J {} awk 'FNR == 1 && !/^($|#)/ { sum+=$1) } 
            END{ print sum }' {} >> cS_CPU.txt
    x=$(( x+1 ))
    done
```

- need for `-F' '` ? awk will separate field by space
- `"S_$((x))x$((x))*"` ? can be turn into "S_${x}x${x}*".

Comment: "S_$((x))x$((x))*"  works fine as well ;)
-F' ' is a remnant of an old code. It does not do anything here as I have one column only.
My problem is to find the right format for the sum. $1 are all of the format 6.432e-07. How do I sum over them?

Comment: @JulianeKiqhwdf: `$((x))x$((x))` may "work", but it is pointless (at best) to do an unnecessary numeric evaluation on a variable which you already know to be the number you want.